# jQuery script modification

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery script change search result link separately, but I want to change it all together, resp. I want to get this link format:

```
?page=1&sort=1&order=1
```

Here is that jQuery script to modificate:

```
    // Change Sort Type
      $(".sort").change(function() {                
            editResults("?page=1&sort="+$(this).val());
      });
    // Change Order Type
      $(".order").change(function() {               
            editResults("?page=1&order="+$(this).val());
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  // Change Sort Type
      $(".sort").change(function() {                
            editResults("?page=1&sort="+$(this).val()+"&order="+$(".order").val());
      });
    // Change Order Type
      $(".order").change(function() {               
            editResults("?page=1&order="+$(this).val()+"&sort="+$(".sort").val());
      });
```

in general:

```
   function changeSortAndOrder(sort, order) {
           editResults("?page=1&order="+order+"&sort="+sort);
   }
```